# How to make an API call to https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/pet/findByStatus?status=available and display a count of the number of pets in the result

Tags: api, count

My code so far:
I called the api using fetch() and converted the data to JSON, but I am not getting the logic to do the count of the number of pets.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Petstrore API</title>
</head>
<body>
    <label>Number of pets:</label><br>
    <textarea id="result"></textarea>
    <script>
     const petStore_url = 'https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/pet/findByStatus?status=available'; 
      async function getPetCount() {
      const response = await fetch(petStore_url);
      const data = await response.json(); //Converting response to JSON 
      console.log(data);
      }
      getPetCount();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it returns an array, you should be able to do Array.length, or in your case data.length to get the count of first level objects (pets).